# POST-ing an URL via AJAX (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a text field on my website that contains an URL, i.e. "http://www.google.com".

When the user changes that field, jQuery sends the change via `POST` to a PHP script that saves it to the database.

The problem is that when jQuery tries to send the value of the changed field (i.e. "http://www.google.com"), a "403 Forbidden" error appears. It seems that "http://" is the problematic part. "ttp://" gets through and so does "http:/".

Does the browser return the error for security reasons? Is there a way around it?

EDIT: The event of changing the text field triggers this:

```js
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "updateproject.php",
data: { "id": id, "field": this.name, "value": this.value }
});
```

EDIT 2: Here's an image of the error. Should I ask my hosting provider about this?
[image]

Comment: It's just a string so it should be fine. Can you show us the code that sends the request?

Comment: Please give us the code to give a reasonable anaswer.

Comment: A base uri must be properly parsed while excluding embedded uri punctuation, which otherwise can be a security risk. Try putting the url in brackets <> and strip them in your form handler.

Comment: Question has been open for 43mins, and still no code provided? Please provide your code.

Comment: Radio, your solution works great! Thank you! In fact, adding any character in the beginning of the URL makes so that I don't get a 403 error - a letter/number, a dot or anything else. It seems that this is the way to go in my case unless there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need encode the url for send it as a parameter.

Check it `encodeURIComponent()`
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help either. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

403 Forbidden is returned by the server not your browser.  It means you need to authenticate (probably send a username and password) to post the data you're sending.

ttp:// and http:/ are not valid uri headers.  So they can't be getting through.  The server most likely is ignoring them.

I also doubt google.com will allow you to cross site post to them.  If you're trying to show their search results on your site you'll want to look into their search API.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem. I don't want to do cross-site stuff. I just want to insert "http://www.google.com" into the database via AJAX. Also, there are other fields besides the one containing an URL that work fine, so it isn't an authentication problem.